# implementing force update with react native apps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been googling for a way to force users to update a react native application before allowing them to use it any further. I have not implemented this before and am searching for a way to approach this.

any insight is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: use bundle version and release channel to check, if the current app is the latest or old, if it's old redirect the user to app store.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [CodePush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native). More specifically you will need to give the codePush options to install immediately.

```
codePush({
    checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
    installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
  })
```

Comment: This just updates the javascript portion of the app. It does not apply if you have updates to the native code.

Comment: I might of miss understood the question. If you want to force a user to update the app itself, then you must bump the app version and send it to the App Store. Once you have done this you can then send an other code push bundle for the old app version with a notice telling them to update the app.

Comment: The OP wants a way to tell the user to go download the latest app from the app store. He or she is not referring to over the air updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force users to update, You can change the main screen to update screen. For example in the main Component (`Provider` for me), I can do this:

```
export default class Provider extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.checkUpdate()
    }
    checkUpdate = () => {
        // Request last version number from your server
        // And compare with current version.
        // You can save this number in device storage with AsyncStorage
        // At last:
        this.setState({
            checked: true,
            updated: true // Or false
        })
     }
     render() {
         let {checked, updated} = this.state
         if(checked){
             if(updated) return <App />
             else return <PleaseUpdate />
         }
         else return <Loading />
     }
}
```

Comment: Would the PleaseUpdate component be a web view of the app store?